# Deploy a Python application to web that interacts with local files

Tags: python, excel, server, web-deployment

**Background:** Am comfortable in Python, know nothing about web deployment. I am looking into it as an alternative to compiling into .exe or .app for Win or Mac distributions.

**Issue:** I have a simple application that uses BeautifulSoup, openpyxl, and PySimplyGUI. It interacts with some local excel-files and creates new ones. I want to be able to, using minimum effort, make it accessible on my own web page or something similar, and make the created excel-files available for browsing/download. I have no idea how to do any of this. I've been looking into Flask and cloud foundry, but it feels like there should be some easy alternative that I'm missing. Ideally I would want a page where someone can log in (given a username and password I supply), which then directs to a page where the user can interact with my application.

**Request:** Is there a relatively easy way to do this that doesn't involve setting up a lot of stuff in html, etc., and where excel-files can still be interacted with by openpyxl? I ideally would just want some template, where I can "fill in the blanks" for the python method I would want to execute for each button!

Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create a web app with a simple interface yet effective which does not require frontend programming is [Streamlit](https://discuss.streamlit.io/). It is primarily used by data scientist to create simple web apps quickly.